# Wordpress exploited theme is causing high io load on server

Tags: wordpress, exploit

I used a Wordpress theme for a while that was causing high IO-load on my server. That was because there was some kind of exploits made/available for the theme: http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/29150/ .
So I deleted my theme, installed another, but "they" are keep coming back. Because the domain name is somewhere registered that it is vulnerable or something like that.
What can I do to stop this? Moving it to another server isn't the solution I guess, because they're pointing to the domain name.
I've already blocked IP-ranges from outside my country, they're pointing to a "forbidden" html page then, but still it are a lot of "things", so the io load stays high.

Comment: "they are keep coming back." - chances are they've added another way into your server then. The simplest thing to do is to reinstall everything on a clean OS image, being very careful what you copy over. You might look on wordpress.stackexchange.com for specific security advice, or serverfault or superuser for general cleaning-up-a-compromise advice.

Comment: Actually moving it to another server *is* the solution, or, perhaps you can contact the hosting company and ask them to clean the things.

Comment: "they're pointing to the domain name" - and remember you control the DNS attached to the domain name, so you can set up a new server and switch that to point to the new server. The problem is the software installed on the current server.

Comment: If by _“"they" are keep coming back”_ you mean that your system is not vulnerable any more, but the same _requests_ are still made – there is not much you can do about that. You can only try to identify parameters that are _specific_ to this kind of request, and try to block them as soon as possible … either in WP pre processing, or already on server level.

Comment: @CBroe that is exactly what is happening. Already reinstalled everything. But I don't get what you mean by your solution.